# Change type sensor_msgs/joint_states to JointMessage

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, ros-hydro, ros-industrial, joint-states

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

My Node is subscribing to a ROS-Node that publishes [sensor_msgs/joint_state](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/JointState.html).
Now I would like to send this data via the [simple_message Protocol](http://wiki.ros.org/simple_message) using TCP/IP to my robot controller.
My goal is to subsribe to the topic "joint_states" which, as I so far understood, is often used for sending actual robot positions and send it over TCP/IP using the "simple_message" protocol.

So there are two possibilities for me:
Get "joint_states" to "simple_message" directly and send it.
or
Convert "joint_states" to "JointMessage" which is part of the "simple_message" Package and send it.

The Communication already works. I followed a ROS-I-Tutorial, which I am not able to find again at the moment.
What the robot controller receives is not important yet. For now a dummy node prints the sequence of the simple message to the screen and this works for the first.

May someone have an idea.

Here is my code-snippet:

```
while(client.isConnected())
{

    ros::spinOnce();
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("POS1 = " << globalJointState.position[1]);

    // Create a message of type JointMessage and corresponding simple message
    industrial::joint_message::JointMessage jmReq;
    industrial::simple_message::SimpleMessage req, reply;

    jmReq.setSequence(globalJointState.header.seq);
    //jmReq.addAllDataIwishForMyJointMessage(outOffMyGlobalJointStates);
    jmReq.toRequest(req);


    ROS_INFO_STREAM("Sending sequence: " << globalJointState.header.seq << " to " << LOCAL_HOST << ":" << TCP_PORT);

    client.sendAndReceiveMsg(req, reply);

    ROS_INFO_STREAM("Received reply code: " << reply.getReplyCode());

    ros::Duration(1).sleep();


}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194526/change-type-sensor_msgs/joint_states-to-jointmessage/) by [RosBort](https://answers.ros.org/users/20405/rosbort/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2014-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> [..] send this data via the simple_message Protocol using TCP/IP to my robot controller. My goal is to subsribe to the topic "joint_states" which, as I so far understood, is often used for sending actual robot positions [..]

Not as far as I know: the `sensor_msgs/JointStates` message is used to store the state of a set of joints at a certain time, as a piece of sensor information -- actual state. It is not normally used to encode desired or commanded state. Server implementations using the protocol -- running on robot controllers -- typically periodically send out `JOINT_POSITION` Simple Message messages, that the `industrial_robot_client` deserialises and republishes as `sensor_msgs/JointStates`.

As such, there is currently no support in `simple_message` for "Convert[ing] 'joint_states' to 'JointMessage' which is part of the 'simple_message' Package and send it".

Do you have a particular reason for wanting to send over `sensor_msgs/JointStates` messages, instead of letting the `industrial_robot_client` proxy between [JointTrajectory](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/trajectory_msgs/html/msg/JointTrajectory.html) and `JOINT_TRAJ_PT` or similar messages?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosBort](https://answers.ros.org/users/20405/rosbort/) on 2014-10-08**:
Thank you for your answer! There is no particular reason for me using sensor_msgs/JointStates. It resulted out of a lack of knowledge. I will read/work through this tomorrow. Thank you and good night (depending on where you live of course ;) )